# python making my own lower case converter

Tags: python, string, for-loop, iteration, lowercase

I am new to programming and I need some help for an free online tutorial to learn Python. I am building my own method to convert a an input string to all lower cases.  I cannot use the string.lower() method. In the code I have so far I cannot figure out how to separate the input string into characters that can be inputed into my character converter lowerChar(char).

```
string=input #input string


def lowerChar(char):              #function for converting characters into lowercase
   if ord(char) >= ord('A') and ord(char)<=ord('Z'):
      return chr(ord(char) + 32)
   else:
      return char

def lowerString(string):     #function for feeding characters of string into lowerChar
   result = ""
  for i in string:
     result = result + lowerChar(string[i])
     return result
```

Comment: Your iteration over the string is wrong. If you do for i in string, you actually already have each character in the variable i. No need for string[i] then.

Comment: You should also put the return statement in lowerString() outside the for loop, otherwise it will work for the first char only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close:

```
def lowerString(string):
  result = ""
  for i in string:
     # i is a character in the string
     result = result + lowerChar(i)
  # This shouldn't be under the for loop
  return result
```

Strings are iterable just like lists!

Also, make sure to be careful about your indentation levels, and the number of spaces you use should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning only the first letter, you have to `return` in a outer scope, try this, also it is better to use `+=` instead of `result = result + lowerChar(i)`

```
def lowerString(string):     #function for feeding characters of string into lowerChar
  result = ""
  for i in string:
     result  += lowerChar(i) 
  return result

print lowerString("HELLO") #hello
```

Answer (score 1):

A tip: You don't need to use ord(). Python can directly do the following comparision:

`if char >= 'A' and char<='Z':`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
string = input("Input one liner: ")

def lowerChar(char):
    if char >= 65 and char <= 90:
        char = chr(char + 32)
        return char
    else:
        char = chr(char)
        return char


def lowerString(string):
    result = ""
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        result = result + lowerChar(ord(string[i]))
    return result

print(lowerString(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def lowerChar(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return chr(ord(c) - ord('A') + ord('a'))
    else:
        return c

def lowerString(string):
    result = ""
    x=0

    for i in string:
        while x < len(string):
           result = result + lowerChar(string[x])
           x+=1

        return result
```